# How to Add an Image/Icon in Line with Text where will still Image/Icon still Appear when maxLines Set

Tags: flutter

### Purpose

What I need is to display the image/icon inline with the text (displays after a Text), however when the maxLine reached image/icon still appears. I have to try with `Row` and `RichText` or `Text.rich`.

---

### Row

Using `Row` is a bad idea because the Image/Icon will not be on a single line with the text when there are more than one line of text.

---

### RichText or Text.rich

Using `RichText` is a good idea, but the Icon will disappear if the Text is too long (`maxLines` reached).

**Example Code:**

```
Text.rich(
  TextSpan(
    children: <InlineSpan>[
       TextSpan(text: "this is long text, really2 loooonnnngg textt. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."),

       // Need to still appear this WidgetSpan Icon
       WidgetSpan(
         alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
         child: Icon(Icons.local_offer)
       ),
    ],
  ),
  maxLines: 2,
),
```

From the code above the `WidgetSpan` that contains `Icon` will be disappear if maxLines reached

---

**Example Output: (but I need with `maxLines` set)**

[image]

or any other ideas to solve this?